# Kubuntu 16.04 - Oracle VM - Boot hangs at Black Screen with '_' - flashes message "int_rapl no valid rapl domains..."

Tags: boot, virtualbox, kubuntu

Upon a normal boot, I see the Kubuntu 16.04 loading in, then it flashes the text intel_rapl no valid rapl domains ... then hangs on a black screen with just a _

I can hold shift, go into GNU GRUB -> Advanced Options -> Ubuntu with Linux 4.4.0-93-generic ( recovery ) -> dpkg (repair broken packages) -> boot into my virtual machine desktop

I did >sudo apt-get upgrade && update

I tried running boot-repair but it doesn't load up the program

I see no way around this issue to boot up normally. Any clues?

Comment: I've also tried unchecking boxes in the VM Oracle settings like 3d Acceleration and Enable PAE

Comment: I have the same issue. My Host OS is Windows 10 Build 15063